# Finding a domain where an integral of a function is '0'

Tags: polynomials

Motivated from reading mr.fourier's tricks, I wanted to come with some of my own to solve some problems of mine.

consider,

$$ P(x) = a_o x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} ... + a_n x^0$$

Now, I multiply  $ x^k$ on both sides with $ k \leq n $

I get,

$$ x^k P(x) = a_o x^{n+k} ... +a_n x^{0+k}$$

Now I integrate both sides over an interval,

$$ \int_{a}^{b} x^k P(x)  = \int_{a}^{b} a_o x^{n+k} ... +a_n x^{0+k}$$

How do I interval such that integral is 0 on the right side for all terms of form $x^{a+k}$ except where $a=k?$

It would be even better if there was some other function I could use for replicating fourier tricks for polynomial functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what you want by playing with intervals, but for "some other function" you probably want [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).

And if you like what Fourier expansions do, you might want to go research the terms "inner product space", "Hilbert space", and [Orthogonal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials).