# $\int _a^bQ(x)\cdot w(x)dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, polynomials, definite-integrals

Consider the following problem:

> Find all functions $w$, where $w$ is a  ***continuous function*** defined on the interval
> $[a,b]$, with $a<b$, and $a\ge0$ and $b>0$ real numbers with the following remarkable
> property:  $$\int _a^bQ(x)\cdot w(x)dx=0$$
> for every:
>
> a) polynomial $Q$ with real coefficients
>
> b) polynomial $Q$ with rational coefficients

***My attempt:***

Firstly, the one thing that can help me solve not only the first part of the problem but also the last one is the following:

I choose $$Q_0(X)=1 ,
Q_1(X)=X, Q_2(X)=X^2,Q_3(X)=X^3,...,Q_K(X)=X^K$$

and then I obtained:

$$\int _a^bX^i\cdot w(x)dx=0$$
for every i from $0$ to $K$.

It goes without saying that:

$$\lim _{K\to \infty }\int _0^1\:\left(x^Kw\left(x\right)\right)dx=0$$

However, I am not sure these would be useful to any of the double problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a domain where an integral of a function is '0'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751531/finding-a-domain-where-an-integral-of-a-function-is-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is equivalent to say that $\langle Q,w\rangle=0$ for evey polynomial $Q$. I don't know what is your background on functional analysis, but the easiest way to solve this is to use the fact that the polynomials are dense in the set of continuous functions (this is called Weierstrass theorem), thus $\langle Q,w\rangle=0$ for evey continuous function $Q$ on $[a,b]$. Hence, we have a function that is orthogonal to all other functions, so it must be the zero function, i.e $w=0$.

For the second part you can argue in the same  way using the fact that the set of polynomials with rational coeficients is dense in the set of poynomials with real coeficients, thus it is dense in the set of continuous functions.

Comment: This is quite sophisticated for this 'elementary problem'. Don't you know something simpler?

Comment: @user141414 Unfortunatelly I don't, that is the only solution I was given by my teacher when he showed us this result. In all the books I read this was a corollary or an exercise on a chapter about aproximation theorems. However, I'm not sure you can't solve this withouth the use of Weierstrass or Stone-Weierstrass theroem.